# Calling format option of Eclipse from command line

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, command-line

I have made customized format setting for C/C++ in Eclipse by going to

```
Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Code Style > Formatter
```

to use it within Eclipse, I use format option within source menu option or KEY BINDING (Ctrl+Shift+F).

My QUESTION

Can i run this format option from command line.

Like calling Eclipse from cmd and add this as arguments
somewhat like

```
 C:/> eclipse -format <filename.c>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look on eclipse [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm) I thing it's possibile calling eclipse like in this way:

```
eclipse -configuration <file_name>
```

Obviously, you have to save all your configuration in a file.